# Omnipay integration with brazilian gateway Cielo

Tags: php, payment-gateway, omnipay

I'm developing a new package to help me use the famous payment gateway Cielo through [omnipay](http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/://)

But I have a few questions, from seeing another omnipay implementations I didn't found the answer for:

- Can I use [this Cielo's library](https://github.com/DeveloperCielo/Webservice-1.5-php) or I need to build everything by my own?
- Cielo has credit card payments. The question is, how do I recognize the card payment network? Is there a correct way or I can create my own flags for development use?

That's all for now, thank you!

Comment: When you say "how do I recognize the card payment network" do you mean Visa/Mastercard?

Comment: Yes, in Brazil there is more than just Visa and Mastercard.... I don't know if there is a correct way to register this payments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

It is recommended that you interface with their API directly instead of using a wrapper library. They have a REST API/web service [here](https://developercielo.github.io/Webservice-3.0/) ([English docs](https://developercielo.github.io/Webservice-3.0/english.html) for those interested).

From a brief look it seems a bit like Stripe so [omnipay-stripe](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-stripe) might be a good place to start.

Unlike Stripe, Cielo seems to support [3D Secure Authentication](https://developercielo.github.io/Webservice-3.0/#criando-uma-venda-com-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) ([English docs](https://developercielo.github.io/Webservice-3.0/english.html#creating-a-sale-with-authentication)) so this will require a bit more work although there are a number of Omnipay gateways that also implement 3D Secure such as [omnipay-realex](https://github.com/coatesap/omnipay-realex)

**Question 2:**

Omnipay [Card object](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-common/blob/731386e54688405a475d6dd43cd6397728cd709e/src/Omnipay/Common/CreditCard.php) supports [detecting a card brand](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-common/blob/731386e54688405a475d6dd43cd6397728cd709e/src/Omnipay/Common/CreditCard.php#L446) using regex based on the number you provide when creating the object.

You can even [add your own brand](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-common/blob/731386e54688405a475d6dd43cd6397728cd709e/src/Omnipay/Common/CreditCard.php#L178) definitions to the [list](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-common/blob/731386e54688405a475d6dd43cd6397728cd709e/src/Omnipay/Common/CreditCard.php#L120), alternatively you could extend Card.php and implement your own default list.